# Concat strings and numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to concat "(" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY ")".  However, mouseX and mouseY are ints, so I tried using a stringstream as follows:

```
std::stringstream pos;
pos << "(" <<  mouseX << ", " << mouseY << ")";
_glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, pos.str());
```

And it doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error:

> mouse.cpp:75: error: cannot convert `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to`const char*' for argument `2' to`void _glutBitmapString(void*, const char*)'

What am I doing wrong in this basic string + integer concatenation?

Comment: Can someone who can edit this change the question to "How do I convert a stringstream to a const char*?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glutBitmapString()` expects a `char*` and you're sending it a string. use .c_str() on the string like so:

```
_glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, pos.str().c_str());
```

Comment: pedantic, but it's really expecting a "const char *".  If it wanted "char *", .c_str() wouldn't work without a const_cast<char *>

Comment: @Tom: the prototype asks for a const char *, so I am not sure why that needed to be mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
_glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, pos.str().c_str());
```

Comment: @Evan Teran, I think the downvote came because before the edit he had a slight mistype?  I upvoted though!